# OpenCV(4.5.5) converting a 16 bit signed image to 16 bit unsigned

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm attempting to create a collage of images that are currently in a 16s format. `cv2.imshow()` doesn't support this image type but I can't figure out how to convert my images. My code and the error I get when I run it are below.

**Edit:** I'm aware that `cv2.imshow()` supports other images types (not just 16u) so I'm happy to convert it to whatever type is easiest.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import shutil
from PIL import Image

source_path = "C:/Users/source/path/"
destination_path = "C:/Users/destination/path"

#copy raw files only from source, and rename them in im1.png, im2.png etc format

if os.path.exists(destination_path):
    print("destination file already exists")
else:
        dir = os.mkdir(destination_path)
        files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_path, "*raw.png"))
        for file in files:
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                shutil.copy2(file, destination_path)

#resize images and flip
for file_name in os.listdir(destination_path):
    image = Image.open(os.path.join(destination_path, file_name))
    new_dimensions = (50, 50)
    output = image.resize(new_dimensions, Image.ANTIALIAS).transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
    output_file_name = os.path.join(destination_path, file_name)
    output.save(output_file_name, quality = 95)


count=1

#rename the files
for file_name in os.listdir(destination_path):
    
    source = destination_path + file_name
    destination = destination_path + "im" + str(count) + ".png"
    os.rename(source, destination)
    globals()["im" + str(count)] = destination
    
    count += 1

#create collage
h_stack1 = np.hstack([im7,im6,im5,im4,im3,im2,im1])
h_stack2 = np.hstack([im8,im9,im10,im11,im12,im13,im14])
h_stack3 = np.hstack([im21,im20,im19,im18,im17,im16,im15])
h_stack4 = np.hstack([im22,im23,im24,im25,im26,im27,im28])
h_stack5 = np.hstack([im35,im34,im33,im32,im31,im30,im29])
h_stack6 = np.hstack([im36,im37,im38,im39,im40,im41,im42])
h_stack7 = np.hstack([im49,im48,im47,im46,im45,im44,im43])
    
v_stack = np.vstack([h_stack1,h_stack2,h_stack3,h_stack4,h_stack5,h_stack6,h_stack7])
    
cv2.imshow("collage",v_stack)
cv2.imsave("collage.png",v_stack)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The issue is with the last 4 lines, and the error is:

```
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - mat data type = 19 is not supported
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::cuda::GpuMat> for argument 'mat'
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'
```

Comment: To display I would suggest normalizing your images to unsigned 8-bit integer to maintain pixel range (0 - 255): `norm_img = cv2.normalize(img, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255,norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)`

Comment: After normalising all the images and re-running the code I get this error instead:
`error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'normalize'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'`

Comment: Please mention details of the error by editing the question. What code did you add? Where did you add it? By looking at the error you have fed the wrong input to `cv2.normalize()`

Comment: I added it immediately before `h_stack1`. For each image (i.e. im1, im2... etc) I did `norm_im1 = cv2.normalize(im1, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255,norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)` and then created the horizontal stacks with the new norm_im 1-49.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing an image *array* and not the image *string*? Check for the data type of `im1` before normalizing

Comment: Ah yes I am passing the image string. I'm not sure how this happened or how to correct it honestly.

Comment: Read every image using `cv2.imread()`. Normalize them and append them

Comment: did you find the problem?